# Converting any colored PPM image into a colored image with only 8 colors

Tags: c++

I need an algorithm for converting any colored image of ppm format to only 8 color in C++. I tried this code and I keep facing an error with the `>>` and `<<` operators:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
ifstream in;
in.open("football.ppm");
ofstream out("football8color.ppm");

string header;
int cols, rows,colors;
int r, g, b;


in >> header >> cols >> rows >> colors;
out << header << endl;
out<< cols<< " " << rows <<endl;
out<< colors<< endl;

for ( int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
        in>> r >> g >> b;
}
out <<endl;
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    return 0 ;
    }
```

I get these errors:

```
    4   IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands   c:\users\atiyeh\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mm ass 2\mm ass 2\mm ass 2.cpp    18
    3   IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands   c:\users\atiyeh\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mm ass 2\mm ass 2\mm ass 2.cpp    17
Error   2   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  c:\users\atiyeh\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mm ass 2\mm ass 2\mm ass 2.cpp    16
Error   1   error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\atiyeh\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mm ass 2\mm ass 2\mm ass 2.cpp    15
```

Comment: What errors?  How would you convert the image down to 8 colors?

Comment: i have no idea if this code is right, doctor gave us this assignment and told us you can use this code but modify it first, anyway when i write this code and reach line 9-12 it gives me error (Error 1 error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\atiyeh\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mm ass 2\mm ass 2\mm ass 2.cpp 15)

Comment: It sounds like you're missing some includes.  Why not edit the question to include the whole cpp file and work on the formatting a bit.  You can add any error you get to the question as well.

Comment: i did some editing, have a look now

Comment: Adding `#include <string>` should fix those errors.  I'm still not sure what you mean by 8 colors as there isn't an 8 color PPM format I know of and you'll need some sort of algorithm to choose the 8 colors and map the existing colors to the new ones.

Comment: thank a lot for your effort, i still have no clue either

Answer (score 0):

For the algorithm, you should look up [Color Quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization). If you want to make it look nice, you should look up [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering) techniques such as Floyd-Stienberg dithering.